# How to get all objects in the scene from a component?

Tags: aframe

What's the right way to get all objects in a scene, while in a component?

If I need to raycast everything, for example.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function () {
    var el = this.el;
    // Get all objects in scene?
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the scene, and then from there all the children. https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/core/entity.html#sceneel

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function () {
    var allObjects = this.el.sceneEl.object3D.children;
  }
});
```

- this: component instance
- el: `<a-entity>` element that component is attached to
- sceneEl: `<a-scene>` element
- object3D: three.js scene object
- children: three.js all objects of scene

Comment: `this.el.getElementsByTagName('*')` is another approach if you want to recursively get children.